# C# NDDE issue with returning data immediately

Tags: c#, dde, ndde

I am following the code example here for ndde to communicate with MS Excel (2010).

https://gist.github.com/atifaziz/9252590

I have fired up the program but can only get it to read the contents of R1C1 when I press enter (perfom the update/poke process).

How can I get the program to immediately return the value of the contents of cell R1C1 upon startup. I have tried client.Request method but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Why on earth would you use DDE for this rather than OLE automation? Not that automation doesn't have its own pitfalls, but at least it's not deprecated like DDE is. Examples for how to automate Excel in C# are much easier to come by. (If at all possible, even OLE automation should be avoided in favor of just generating/manipulating spreadsheets without Excel running; there are several libraries for that too.)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. It needs to be DDE for now